# matplot plot graph side by side

Tags: matplotlib

I need help to plot the graph side by side instead of scrolling down. I can't figure out how to plot side by side.

I would like to show the next boxplot+histogram pic side by side and so on. just 2 boxplot+histogram per rows.

```
cols=bank_data.select_dtypes(['int64','float64']).columns 
for i, variable in enumerate(cols):
  if variable != "CLIENTNUM":
   f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.15, .85)});
   # Add a graph in each part
   sns.boxplot(bank_data[variable], ax=ax_box);
   sns.histplot(bank_data[variable], bins=12, kde=True, stat='density',ax=ax_hist);
   ax_box.axvline(np.mean(bank_data[variable]),color='g',linestyle='-')
   ax_hist.axvline(np.mean(bank_data[variable]),color='g',linestyle='-')
   ax_hist.axvline(np.median(bank_data[variable]),color='y',linestyle='--')
   plt.tight_layout()
```

[boxplot+histogram pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxClV.png)

Comment: got this error using ncols=2 - Expected the given number of height ratios to match the number of rows of the grid

Comment: oh without the gridspec its showing 2 separate graphs. I want have boxplot+histplot ( row1,col1) use the same x axis but when for loop run next iteration of the graph ( boxplot+histplot) should be side by side( row1, col2) instead of just 1 column.